# Does complex sql queries should happen in Backend or its safe to do in android mobile

Tags: java, android, mysql, performance, android-room

Is it ok to do complex sql queries in mobile? I am using ionic with android (java) and have two databases with Room DB. which contains 9600 entries each. I want to perform some complex queries like get 'firstname' which contain char 'demo', having age more then '70' and and and.

So my questions are:

1. does this kinda queries make mobile slow even they async?
2. should it better to send request to backend and let it do the calculation (backend have same DB).
3. old mobiles with less RAM might not work?? right

Thanks

Comment: Async task won't slow down your app as the work is being done on a separate thread. However, the time taken to get the results from DB may vary depending on the specifications of the device.

Comment: 9600 records are not much even for a mobile. With `backend` you mean via an online api? That sounds like a horrible user experience, data usage and lots of more work to implement.